# Can I SSH into my EC2 instance created by terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform, ssh-keys

I have created an EC2 instance using terraform (I do not have the `.pem` keys). Can I establish an SSH connection between my local system and the EC2 instance?

Comment: You should generate a .pem key and add is as a `aws_key_pair` resource. The use `key_name` in your `aws_instance`. It might be possible to set it with `user data` but not preferred.

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code used?

Comment: you need an internet gateway

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming you provisioned an instance using Terraform `v0.12.+` with this structure:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami              = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type    = "t2.micro"
  count            = 1
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}
```

You can make some additional settings:

- Configure the public ip `output`:

```
output "instance_ip" {
  description = "The public ip for ssh access"
  value       = aws_instance.instance.public_ip
}
```

- Create an `aws_key_pair` with an existing ssh public key or create a [new one](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)
  Ex:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "ssh-key" {
  key_name   = "ssh-key"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza............"
}
```

- Add the `key_name` in `instance` resource just like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami              = var.ami
  instance_type    = "t2.micro"
  count            = 1
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  key_name         = "ssh-key"
}
```

- Now you need to apply running `terraform apply` and `terraform output` to return the public IP
- Get your public IP and run:

```sh
 ssh <PUBLIC IP>
```

OR with a public key path

```sh
ssh -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" <PUBLIC IP>
```

Sources:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: I tried this, got `ssh: connect to host 54.212.XX.XX port 22: Operation timed out`.

Comment: @ijt You need to verify if port 22 is open in the Security Group, check this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html